# universal_robot package for ROS Kinetic

Tags: ros, moveit, ubuntu, universal-robot, ubuntu-xenial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Currently I am working on some movement planning projects with [UR3](https://www.universal-robots.com/products/ur3-robot/), and one of the ideas is to use [Raspberry Pi 3 model B](https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/raspberry-pi-3-model-b/) as a computing center for robot's motion planning. The issue is that Ubuntu development team officially supports only Ubuntu 16.04 Xenial version for RPi3, and even Ubunty Trusty image for Raspberry Pi **2** is no longer maintained.
As we tested, there is no problem to install Ubuntu Xenial with Kinetic on RPi3, but the problem is that officially `universal_robot` driver is not compatible with Kinetic, so it won't work.

1. Is there plans to develop ROS Kinetic version for driver, with compatibility with moveit planner?
2. Maybe there are other solutions for computing boards with Trusty + Indigo, do you know some?

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/254575/universal_robot-package-for-ros-kinetic/) by [Ilya Boyur](https://answers.ros.org/users/28919/ilya-boyur/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2017-02-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Edit: `ur_modern_driver` has Kinetic support and is now hosted at [ros-industrial/ur_modern_driver](https://github.com/ros-industrial/ur_modern_driver). Be sure to use the `kinetic-devel` branch.

---

Original answer:

I prefer the `ur_modern_driver` over `ur_driver` (in `universal_robot`).  Github page [here](https://github.com/ThomasTimm/ur_modern_driver).

It doesn't have official Kinetic support yet either but there is a user fork available that should work as discussed in [issue 58](https://github.com/ThomasTimm/ur_modern_driver/issues/58).  I would hope/expect that a Kinetic branch will be added soon as there is significant demand.

---

Originally posted by [BrettHemes](https://answers.ros.org/users/20527/bretthemes/) with karma: 525 on 2017-02-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-02-13**:
I agree about `ur_modern_driver` being the preferred package, but just to clarify: only for the driver. `universal_robot` still provides the rest of the packages (robot support, moveit, etc).

**Comment by [Ilya Boyur](https://answers.ros.org/users/28919/ilya-boyur/) on 2017-02-14**:
And because of that support, it is not that clear when we are talking about Kinetic compatibility. I am using `ur_modern_driver` too, but it also has dependencies with `universal_robot` and that package just a replacer for old `ur_driver`